# Unexpected token * exception when run by pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I get the following exception when trying to start a node process over pm2 - when I execute the app.js directly everything is working just fine. I see that in the stack trace there is the node_modules folder of pm2 mentioned - why is that?

```
30|MyPm2Process  | /smprod/dev-backend/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/stream-parser.js:60
30|MyPm2Process  |   static async *parseTokens(iterable, debug, options, colMetadata = []) {
30|MyPm2Process  |                ^
30|MyPm2Process  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
30|MyPm2Process  |     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:70:39)
30|MyPm2Process  |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Node version: 14.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating pm2 to the latest version as described [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/update-pm2/) fixed the issue immediatelly.

Answer (score 1):

Update your pm2 to the latest version
[Link](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/update-pm2/)