# SyntaxError: Unexpected token * after importing sequelize model db object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I am working on an app where I have to connect and perform queries on an SQL server using Sequelize. I have created migrations, seeders, and models using sequelize init but now when I tried to create an object of models using const db = require("./models") it is throwing error like

```
D:\Code Practice\express-sequelize-demo\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:85
  static async *parseTokens(iterable, debug, options, colMetadata = []){
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code Practice\express-sequelize-demo\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:10:44)
```

Files I created

1. package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mssql": "^7.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "tedious": "^11.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

2. app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8088;

// throwing error here after importing
const db = require("./models");

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    status: 1,
    message: "Hello from User",
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    status: 1,
    message: "Welcome to Home Page",
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

3. models/index.js

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
  console.log(sequelize);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

4. models/user.js

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  User.init({
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    bio: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

5)config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "SA",
    "password": "Password123",
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mssql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "Password123",
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mssql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "Password123",
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mssql"
  }
}
```

Comment: share `.env` configuration

Comment: I am not yet using .env file because I am using the local development environment. const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"; I have added config.json file.

Comment: the mssql server is online ?

Comment: Yes, the MSSQL server is online because I can run db:migrate & db:seed:all command successfully.

Comment: share full source with github

Comment: @MERN Please find source code on GitHub 
https://github.com/JayeshGatkal/express-sequelize-demo.git

Comment: i checked the project, and, there is no problem, do you runing with `node app.js` ? or, `pm2 start app.js` ?

Comment: what is your node version ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867493/unexpected-token-exception-when-run-by-pm2

Comment: I am running using nod app.js and using pm2 start. Also, I have the Node 8.11.4 version.

Comment: And my mssql server running as a docker image. So do I need to take some extra steps?

Comment: you need upgrade pm2

Comment: Here the issue was when I try to create sequelize instances using

const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB connection parameters);


it was throwing that error.

But after some research, I updated my node version from 8.11.4 to 14.17.0 and it worked. Now without any error, I can run my application and it is working as expected.

Comment: you can share your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by updating the node version.

Here the issue was when I try to create sequelize instances using

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB connection params); //pass the actual db config
```

it was throwing that error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

But after some research, I updated my node version from 8.11.4 to 14.17.0 and it worked. Now without any error, I can run my application and it is working as expected.